# How can one select slicers with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, powerbi

I am wanting to know how to select slicers in power bi using selenium with Python.

Although I do suspect that this is not really power bi specific and more of just how to use selenium with specific html.

Please see my below image for an example:

[Imgur Link - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Cmm.png)

So I want to click the dropdown that is highlighted and then select one (or several) of the options that are there.

It seems like the structure is something like divs within divs.... until you get to the checkbox (see screenshot below).

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsozF.png)

I am new to selenium and don't know much html so it is too difficult for me to figure out how to select one with selenium and I would appreciate if someone could assist me with how to click one of the filters with selenium + python.

It seems like it is dynamic as well so I am really stuck. All the examples I have done so far have been basic search bars that have an id I can easily use to identify what I want.

To get to the webpage click here:

[Microsoft PBI Report](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)

and click the sample report and when that loads run the code to generate the report and you will get to my first screenshot.

Thank you!

Comment: ^^^ What @JeffC said + refrain from screenshots over code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Power BI online is really not a great place to start learning automation, given all of the dynamic elements on the page. Even as an experienced automation engineer, this site is extremely complex.

Before you can do anything with the report, you need to switch to the `iframe` element that the  report exists in.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'reportContainer')]/iframe");
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Once you do that, you can start selecting filters. Here's how I would select the 'Month' filter:

```
# expand the 'Month' filter
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//filter[li/div/div/h2[contains(@title, 'Date')]]").click()
```

This will just expand the filter. Now, we have to select an item from the checkboxes:

```
# select "jan-14"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Jan-14')]").click()
```

You will need to update your XPaths to click different elements, given certain text parameters. For example, if you want to select `isVanArsdel` instead of `Month`, you'd have to modify the XPath selector as such:

```
# expand the 'isVanArsdel' filter
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//filter[li/div/div/h2[contains(@title, 'isVanArsdel')]]").click()
```

Due to the nature of this page, it's likely that your problems will not end here. Be prepared to try out different methods to click elements, such as Javascript click.

If regular Selenium `.click()` does not work, you can execute Javascript to click:

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("someXPath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)
```

Hope this helps a bit.